# distribute `n` among `k` units without repetition and zero structures in R

Tags: r, function, math, combinations, combinatorics

I was wondering if there might be a way in R to distribute `n` among `k` units without repetition (e.g., `3 5 2` is the same as `5 3 2`, and `2 3 5` and `5 2 3`) and without considering `0` combinations (i.e., no `9 1 0`) and see the make-up of this distribution?

For example if `n = 9` and `k = 3` then we expect the make-up to be:

(Note: `k` will always be the # of columns)

`3 3 3 
4 3 2
4 1 4
5 2 2
5 1 3
6 2 1
7 1 1`

```
 makeup <- function(n, k){

  # your suggested solution #
 }
```

Comment: Why does the result have 7 rows?

Comment: No, I  just didn't understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called integer partitions (more specifically restricted integer partitions) and can efficiently be generated with the packages `partitions` or `arrangements` like so:

```
partitions::restrictedparts(9, 3, include.zero = FALSE)

[1,] 7 6 5 4 5 4 3
[2,] 1 2 3 4 2 3 3
[3,] 1 1 1 1 2 2 3

arrangements::partitions(9, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    7
[2,]    1    2    6
[3,]    1    3    5
[4,]    1    4    4
[5,]    2    2    5
[6,]    2    3    4
[7,]    3    3    3
```

They are much faster than the solutions thus provided:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(arrangePack = arrangements::partitions(20, 5),
               partsPack = partitions::restrictedparts(20, 5, include.zero = FALSE),
               myfun2(20, 5, 20),
               myfun1(20, 5, 20),
               makeup(20, 5),
               mycomb(20, 5), times = 3, unit = "relative")
Unit: relative
              expr          min           lq        mean       median          uq         max neval
       arrangePack     1.000000     1.000000    1.000000     1.000000    1.000000    1.000000     3
         partsPack     3.070203     2.755573    2.084231     2.553477    1.854912    1.458389     3
 myfun2(20, 5, 20) 10005.679667  8528.784033 6636.284386  7580.133387 5852.625112 4872.050067     3
 myfun1(20, 5, 20) 12770.400243 10574.957696 8005.844282  9164.764625 6897.696334 5610.854109     3
     makeup(20, 5) 15422.745155 12560.083171 9248.916738 10721.316721 7812.997976 6162.166646     3
     mycomb(20, 5)  1854.125325  1507.150003 1120.616461  1284.278219  950.015812  760.280469     3
```

In fact, for the example below, the other functions will error out because of memory:

```
system.time(arrangements::partitions(100, 10))
 user  system elapsed 
0.068   0.031   0.099 

arrangements::npartitions(100, 10)
[1] 2977866
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try `gtools::combinations` for this work like below with `repeats.allowed=TRUE` option:

```
m <- gtools::combinations(9, 3, repeats.allowed = TRUE)
m[rowSums(m) == 9,]
```

A probable function could be, with `options(expressions = 500000)`, this function could go till n = 500 (successfully ran on my machine for `n=500`, r=3):

```
mycomb <- function(n, r, sumval){
    m <- combinations(n, r, repeats.allowed = TRUE)
    m[rowSums(m) == sumval,]
}
mycomb(9,3,9)
```

**Output**:

```
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    1    7
#[2,]    1    2    6
#[3,]    1    3    5
#[4,]    1    4    4
#[5,]    2    2    5
#[6,]    2    3    4
#[7,]    3    3    3
```

Answer (score 1):

using matrix in base R:

```
myfun1 <- function( n, k){
  x <- as.matrix(expand.grid( rep(list(seq_len(n)), k)))
  x <- x[rowSums(x) == n,]
  x[ ! duplicated( t( apply(x, 1, sort)) ),]
}
myfun1( n = 9, k = 3 )
```

May be this using `data.table`.

```
myfun2 <- function( n, k){
  require('data.table')
  dt <- do.call(CJ, rep(list(seq_len(n)), k))
  dt <- dt[rowSums(dt) == n,]
  dt[which(!duplicated(dt[, transpose(lapply( transpose(.SD), sort ))])),]
}

myfun2( n = 9, k = 3 )
#    V1 V2 V3
# 1:  7  1  1
# 2:  6  2  1
# 3:  5  3  1
# 4:  4  4  1
# 5:  5  2  2
# 6:  4  3  2
# 7:  3  3  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base solution using `expand.grid`.  I'm not going to recommend it for large `n`, but it works:

```
makeup <- function(n, k) {
  x <- expand.grid(rep(list(1:n), 3)) # generate all combinations
  x <- x[rowSums(x) == n,]            # filter out stuff that doesn't sum to n
  x <- as.data.frame(t(apply(x, 1, sort))) # order everything
  unique(x)                                # keep non-duplicates
}
```

A little rethinking simplifies this greatly.  If we have a vector of `n` objects, we can break it apart at `n-1` different spots..  starting from this, we can reduce the work substantially:

```
makeup <- function(n, k) {
  splits <- combn(n-1, k-1) # locations where to split up the data

  bins <- rbind(rep(0, ncol(splits)), splits) # add an extra "split" before the 1st element
  x <- apply(bins, 2, function(x) c(x[-1],9) -x) # count how many items in each bin

  x <- as.data.frame(t(apply(x, 2, sort))) # order everything
  unique(x)                                # keep non-duplicates
}
```

Comment: Melisa, thank you, can we adapt your function to work in "large-n" situations as well?

Comment: the limitation is that x is originally n^3 X k .  R can handle pretty big numbers, but if you're too big, n^3 can get large.  :)  I'm still thinking on this though.

Comment: it's down to a more reasonable size - order (n^2).

Comment: you will do better using a package where these operations are implemented in a compiled language - those apply statements are fundamentally loops, and they are slow.

Comment: Why your solutions fails when `n = 120` & `k = 12`?

Comment: apparenty it's an issue with the `combn` function.  I figured that being part of R it would be implemented using memory-efficient and speedy compiled code.  type `combn` into R and you will see that not only is it not, but it wants to define a matrix with `ncol = choose(n, k)`.  Needless to say, this fails.